# Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method resync on channel razorpay_flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, razorpay

Trying to integrate RazorPay with **flutter web**. But encountering the below issue.
[image]

Below is the code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'razor_credentials.dart' as razorCredentials;

/*void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Razorpay Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}*/

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _razorpay = Razorpay();

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, _handlePaymentSuccess);
      _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, _handlePaymentError);
      _razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, _handleExternalWallet);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) {
    // Do something when payment succeeds
    print(response);
    verifySignature(
      signature: response.signature,
      paymentId: response.paymentId,
      orderId: response.orderId,
    );
  }

  void _handlePaymentError(PaymentFailureResponse response) {
    print(response);
    // Do something when payment fails
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(response.message ?? ''),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleExternalWallet(ExternalWalletResponse response) {
    print(response);
    // Do something when an external wallet is selected
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(response.walletName ?? ''),
      ),
    );
  }

// create order
  void createOrder() async {
    String username = razorCredentials.keyId;
    String password = razorCredentials.keySecret;
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'))}';

    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "amount": 100,
      "currency": "INR",
      "receipt": "rcptid_11"
    };
    var res = await http.post(
      Uri.https(
          "api.razorpay.com", "v1/orders"), //https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'authorization': basicAuth,
      },
      body: jsonEncode(body),
    );

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      openGateway(jsonDecode(res.body)['id']);
    }
    print(res.body);
  }

  openGateway(String orderId) {
    var options = {
      'key': razorCredentials.keyId,
      'amount': 100, //in the smallest currency sub-unit.
      'name': 'Aegle Link Solutions',
      'order_id': orderId, // Generate order_id using Orders API
      'description': 'Fine T-Shirt',
      'timeout': 60 * 5, // in seconds // 5 minutes
      'prefill': {
        'contact': '9123456789',
        'email': 'ary@example.com',
      }
    };
    _razorpay.open(options);
  }

  verifySignature({
    String? signature,
    String? paymentId,
    String? orderId,
  }) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'razorpay_signature': signature,
      'razorpay_payment_id': paymentId,
      'razorpay_order_id': orderId,
    };

    var parts = [];
    body.forEach((key, value) {
      parts.add('${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(key)}='
          '${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(value)}');
    });
    var formData = parts.join('&');
    var res = await http.post(
      Uri.https(
        "10.0.2.2", // my ip address , localhost
        "razorpay_signature_verify.php",
      ),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // urlencoded
      },
      body: formData,
    );

    print(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(res.body),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _razorpay.clear(); // Removes all listeners

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Razorpay Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                createOrder();
              },
              child: const Text("Pay Rs.100"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Tried to restarting the browser,laptop and added "proguard-rules.pro" in Android->app folder
[image]

and added build types in build.gradle
[image]

Any ideas how to proceed with this? Do I have to create an another project and implement again? Your ideas will be so much helpful!

Comment: usually this error happens when the package is new you can solve it by turning off the app restarting again

Comment: `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get` -> `flutter run`

Comment: Hi Matthew, Tried the same but no luck.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I stopped the web and Visual Studio both. I know it is very dumb, but I have restarted my laptop too hoping for better but was facing the same issue